# Spivak Chapter 13 Problem 34 Proof $\lim_{x \to \infty} 1/x \int_{0}^{x}f(t) dt =a $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-verification

The problem says:

> Suppose f is continuous and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=a$. Prove that:
> $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x}{f(t) dt}=a.$$
>
> Indication: The condition $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=a$ implies that $f(t)$ is close to $a$ for some $ t\geq N$ for some N. This means that $\int_{N}^{N+M} f(t) dt$ is close to $Ma$. If $M$ is large in comparison to $N$, then $Ma/(M+N)$ is close to $a$

I found a solution but it is very different compared to mine.

Here is what I did:
Let $x= M+N$, where $N$ is a constant. So the limit becomes
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N+M} \int_{0}^{N+M}f(t)~ dt $$
The integral can be split as follows:
$$\int_{0}^{N+M}f(t)~ dt=\int_{0}^{N}f(t)~ dt +\int_{N}^{N+M}f(t)~ dt  $$
We can go back to the limit:
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N+M} \left[ \int_{0}^{N}f(t)~ dt +\int_{N}^{N+M}f(t)~ dt  \right] $$
As N is a constant, the integral $ \int_{0}^{N}f(t)~ dt$ is also a constant. Then:
$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N+M} \int_{0}^{N}f(t)~ dt = 0 $$
So our main limit is now:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x}{f(t) dt}=\lim_{M \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N+M} \int_{N}^{N+M}f(t)~ dt$$
Then, it follows form the indications that:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x}{f(t) dt}=\lim_{M \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{N+M} \int_{N}^{N+M}f(t)~ dt = a$$

I would like to know if this is a valid approach. Especially if it is valid to change the limit with $x=N+M$;  and if it is right to cancel the integral from $0$ to $N$, as $N$ is a constant.

Comment: Yes! I have just corrected it

Comment: So the general structure is fine, but I might couch things with epsilon arguments instead (at the end). It would be a bit more rigorous that way.

Comment: Right approach. Now  for $r>0$ take $N4 such that 4x>N\implies |f(x)-a|<r.$  Then for $x=N+M>N$  the value of $(N+M)^{-1}\int_{N_r}^{N+M}f(t)dt$ lies between  $ M(a-r)/(M+N)$ and $M(a+r)/(M+N).$

Comment: What was the use of continuity of $f$ in this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Note that by the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) we may also apply L'Hopital (we just need that the denominator diverges to $+\infty$) and prove the result in a much shorter way
$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{\int_{0}^{x}{f(t) dt}}{x} \stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{\frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{0}^{x}{f(t) dt}\right)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x)}=\lim_{x \to +\infty} \dfrac{f(x)}{1}=a.$$